# Unity: How do I pass as a parameter, a nested list initialized in its own class, to a method?

Tags: unity-game-engine, methods, parameters, parameter-passing, nested-lists

I will try to keep this to the point. I have created a nested list of GameObjects with:

`[System.Serializable] public class TabSlots { public List<GameObject> tabslots; } [System.Serializable] public class Tablature { public List<TabSlots> tablature; } public Tablature allSlots = new Tablature();`

This worked quite well, and I was able to drop the appropriate GameObject(s)
into their respective slots in the Inspector, which hierarchy looked like this:

AllSlots (This is the root of the nested list)
Tablature (12 elements)
Tabslots (3 elements)

I was able to successfully access the components of each GameObject in Tabslots. In the following example, I move an object in deck[0] to the position of allSlots.tablature[0].tabslots[0]. (deck is simply a one-level list of GameObjects)

`deck[0].transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(deck[0].transform.position, allSlots.tablature[0].tabslots[0].transform.position, 70f * Time.deltaTime);`

My QUESTION: How do I send the nested list created by: public Tablature allSlots = new Tablature(); to an IEnumerator method?

I have tried every possible combination I can think of for the call ( ??? represents the undiscovered code).

`StartCoroutine(MyTest(deck, ??? ));`

And also tried everything I could think of with the parameter list in the IEnumertor method ( ??? represents the undiscovered code).

`IEnumerator MyTest((List<GameObject> list1, ??? ))`

Can someone help me fill in the ??? blanks?

Thank you forward.

I have tried all the combinations of reference that I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the type that you created:

```
        ...
        StartCoroutine(MyTest(deck, allSlots));
    }
    private IEnumerator MyTest(List<GameObject> deck, Tablature tablature)
    {
        return null;
    }
```